# card not responsive using bootstrap after inserting a form

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am creating a form that is wrapped inside a card in bootstrap. It worked fine on my pc. However, my page is unresponsive when it comes to small screens because of it. What is wrong?
The code is too long to paste here but here is the code where the card is:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row row-content justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 ">
    <div class="card ">
      <h3 class="card-header badge-warning text-white">Reserve a Table</h3>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-form-label col-xs-12 col-sm-2" for="tables">Number of Guests</label>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline col-xs-2">
              <input class="radio-inline form-check-input" type="radio" name="tables1" id="tables1">
              <label for="tables1" class="fom-check-label">1</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline col-xs-2">
              <input class="radio-inline form-check-input" type="radio" name="tables2" id="tables2">
              <label for="tables2" class="fom-check-label">2</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline col-xs-2">
              <input class="radio-inline form-check-input" type="radio" name="tables3" id="tables3">
              <label for="tables3" class="fom-check-label">3</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline col-xs-2">
              <input class="radio-inline form-check-input" type="radio" name="tables4" id="tables4">
              <label for="tables4" class="fom-check-label col-xs-2">4</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline col-xs-2">
              <input class="radio-inline form-check-input" type="radio" name="tables5" id="tables5">
              <label for="tables5" class="fom-check-label">5</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline col-xs-2">
              <input class="radio-inline form-check-input" type="radio" name="tables6" id="tables6">
              <label for="tables6" class="fom-check-label">6</label>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="time" class="col-12 col-md-2 col-form-label">Date and Time</label>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time" name="time" placeholder="Time">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

'''
P.S. I have no CSS related to it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is position `row` and `col-*`. Then I changed `radio button` name for same `name=tables` because if a different `name` can't changed a pill.

**Here an example:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row row-content justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 ">
    <div class="card ">
      <h3 class="card-header badge-warning text-white">Reserve a Table</h3>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <label class="col-form-label" for="tables">Number of Guests</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline col-xs-2">
              <input class="radio-inline form-check-input" type="radio" name="tables" id="tables1">
              <label for="tables1" class="fom-check-label">1</label>
            </div>
  
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="radio-inline form-check-input" type="radio" name="tables" id="tables2">
              <label for="tables2" class="fom-check-label">2</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="radio-inline form-check-input" type="radio" name="tables" id="tables3">
              <label for="tables3" class="fom-check-label">3</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="radio-inline form-check-input" type="radio" name="tables" id="tables4">
              <label for="tables4" class="fom-check-label col-xs-2">4</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="radio-inline form-check-input" type="radio" name="tables" id="tables5">
              <label for="tables5" class="fom-check-label">5</label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="radio-inline form-check-input" type="radio" name="tables" id="tables6">
              <label for="tables6" class="fom-check-label">6</label>
            </div>
            </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="time" class="col-form-label">Date and Time</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="time" name="time" placeholder="Time">
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, man it worked, can you explain it more if I'm not taking your time. I understand the radio button name but what do you mean by position row and col*. The way I did it was using sm sizing and above while you put md and above is this the problem. Anyways really thank you for this. Wish I can upvote but I'm less 15 pt reputation.

Comment: Firstly, you put a `<div class="row">` into `<div class="form-group row">` then `col-*` can't put like a `<div class="form-check form-check-inline col-xs-2">` *this your mistake*. Please make a row with `<div class="row">` then `<div class="col-12blablabla">`, after it you can put your object target